# Why does part of my page not position center with the browser size?

Tags: css, html, positioning

I can't work this out :-(

everything else moves but that main picture and 3 buttons to the right

http://www.e-fluential.com/offline/

Comment: Your `.slideshow` class in `styles.css` has them set to a fixed location (top and left specified). These should be switched to a fluid layout if that's what you're going for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lee,
Take a look at the CSS for the other parts that are working. You have them defined with a width and the Margin:auto which is making them center.

To correct your header, you should provide a wrapper for the header components, and make sure you define the width, position:relative since you are using absolute position for the slideshow, and set the margin to '0 auto' which will create no top or bottom margin, but center to container.

CSS Example:
`#header-wrap{
width:1000px;
margin:0 auto;
position:relative;
height:363px;
}`

Hope this helps,
Chad